# Liferay 6.1 LDAP import degrading system performance

Tags: ldap, liferay

My portal is able to successfully authenticate with LDAP server (Active Directory) but due to liferay scheduler importing users after some interval, my system performance is degrading. I can see high memory and CPU usage for JAVA and MySql process.

As Active directory is not configured properly, I can see many exceptions related to users not imported due to some issue in log files. As per log file I have added few filters in LDAP query to filter relevant entities (users).

I am using following filter in control panel for *Import Search Filter*:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*@myorg.com)(extensionAttribute1=*))
```

“extensionAttribute1” is used for employee ID. (Mail and employee id entry is used to filter required data.)

To organize data in active directory properly it will take some time but I want some immediate workaround for this issue, like import only on login attempt by user etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import user data only due to his login you have to disable "Ldap import enabled" leaving the LDAP enabled.

You can do this using control panel or by portal-ext.properties

And also to avoid low system performance you can setup a small import page size (default si 1000, you can set 20) and narrow import time interval.

see `ldap.import.interval` and `ldap.page.size` in portal.properties

Comment: Thanks for putting me in right direction. I can see that after disabling "Ldap import enabled" system performance is improved. But I want to know that if "LDAP enabled" and "LDAP Required" is enabled then it will import new users on login attempt ? Also, what is recommended value for ldap.import.interval and ldap.page.size ?

Comment: The recommendation depends on your requirement and the nature of your LDAP data: If they rarely change, but you want the updates frequently, go weekly or monthly. With any interval, the individual users are synchronized whenever they login - so a logged in user always has current data, even if they were never batch-imported. So you can technically also go with no batch import at all.

Comment: The LDAP data on my server is changing frequently, everyday many users will change their password and weekly many users will join or leave the organization. But I don’t want to do batch import as it will affect system performance. I think LDAP enabled and required will work fine (correct me if I am missing something) and I am not setting ldap.import.interval and  ldap.page.size.
With current settings existing user is able to login with new credentials but just want to confirm that Liferay will import new user on login attempt?

Comment: confirmed. And it's easy to test: Change your password in LDAP, then immediately log in to Liferay.