# Import Users and user groups from LDAP in Liferay portal 6.2

Tags: import, liferay, openldap, opendj

I'm trying to import users from an Ldap server.

Here is my Ldap users :

[image]

Liferay Portal ldap settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

By clicking "Test Ldap Users" users are also displayed.
[image]
Problem is that there is no error in liferay log file but no user is importing is there any mistake i am doing. Any help will be appreciated.

**Updated:**

```
05:47:16,332 DEBUG [http-bio-8787-exec-7][PortalLDAPUtil:41] -- listing properties --__java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory__java.naming.provider.url=ldap://142.56.23.10:389/__com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=500__java.naming.security.principal=cn=Directory Manager__com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true__java.naming.security.credentials=cpassword__java.naming.referral=follow__com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout=15000__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,710 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPUtil:41] -- listing properties --__java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory__java.naming.provider.url=ldap://142.56.23.10:389/__com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=500__java.naming.security.principal=cn=Directory Manager__com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true__java.naming.security.credentials=cpassword__java.naming.referral=follow__com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout=15000__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,714 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__password=userPassword__lastName=sn__screenName=uid__firstName=givenName__emailAddress=mail__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,714 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,715 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,715 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,715 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,717 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__password=userPassword__lastName=sn__screenName=uid__firstName=givenName__emailAddress=mail__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,718 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,718 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,719 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,721 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPUtil:593] LDAP user attribute sn: Amar
05:48:28,722 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPUtil:593] LDAP user attribute userPassword: [B@d586ba
05:48:28,722 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPUtil:593] LDAP user attribute uid: user.0
05:48:28,722 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPUtil:593] LDAP user attribute givenName: Aaccf
05:48:28,723 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPUtil:593] LDAP user attribute mail: user.0@maildomain.net
05:48:28,723 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][DefaultLDAPToPortalConverter:102] Screen name user.0 and email address user.0@maildomain.net
05:48:28,723 INFO  [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPImporterImpl:1226] Skipping user user.0@maildomain.net because the LDAP entry was never modified
05:48:28,738 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalLDAPUtil:41] -- listing properties --__java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory__java.naming.provider.url=ldap://142.56.23.10:389/__com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=500__java.naming.security.principal=cn=Directory Manager__com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true__java.naming.security.credentials=cpassword__java.naming.referral=follow__com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout=15000__ [Sanitized]
05:48:28,738 DEBUG [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][LDAPSettingsUtil:41] -- listing properties --__password=userPassword__lastName=sn__screenName=uid__firstName=givenName__emailAddress=mail__ [Sanitized]
```

Comment: Did you hit the "Test LDAP Connection" button? What was the result? Did you restart the server or tried to login with an existing user?

Comment: Additionally, you might try reindexing your users after the import (from Server Administration). But definitely take Tobias Liefke's suggestions, as well.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I have clicked on Test LDAP Connection button. users are displaying by clicking button but not imported when i open users tab and check users.

Comment: According to your log, `user.0@maildomain.net` does exist in the Liferay database already - the importer only shows the `never modified` message, if the user exists in Liferay and the `modifyTimestamp` attribute does not exist in LDAP. So please check again, if you really can't find the user `user.0@maildomain.net` in the control panel. Maybe the user is inactive for some reason, you should check these users as well.

Comment: this is right but i import other users which doeas not exists but its taking much time after staring liferay server to import users.

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot this further by turning up your log levels to debug for the ldap related packages/classes. Be very careful when doing this in production as the logs fill up very quickly.

1. Go to `Control Panel > Server Administration > Log Levels`
2. Set Log Levels to "`ALL`" for the following:

   - com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LDAPAuth
   - com.liferay.portal.security.ldap
   - com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPUtil
3. Click the "`Add Category`" Button
4. Add "`com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporter`" with the "`ALL`" Log Levels

   5. Check the logs.

The above log levels have helped me to debug LDAP import issues many times. You can also test with Tobias's suggestion and also clicking `test user import` button while the logs are at debug levels to give you an insight on what is going on.

You should also verify if the individual user import is happening on login (by login and then checking the logs).

You can reset the log levels back to defaults by restarting your server or reverting back the levels to what they were prior, manually by following the process above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got something in log and going to edit it in my question.kindly see and provide help if possible.

Comment: Looks like your user record is already imported per the logs. Do you see it under Control Panel -> users with your uid/screenname and email/mail?

Comment: If you see the user under Control Panel -> users, that tells me your import on login is working. You may need to look at the batch import process next to see if you can debug it.

Comment: its importing users but its taking too much time after starting liferay to import users. why??

Comment: I am glad that the import is working. Did you change something? How many users do you have that need to be imported? You can think of tuning the import process after we know your volume and requirements on why you want to bulk load all your users. We used to import all users but changed it to import on login only because our anticipated user base increased exponentially and we did not want to run into performance or import issues.

Comment: You should also refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280438/liferay-6-1-ldap-import-degrading-system-performance?rq=1

Comment: ok @Vc1 i'll try and let you know what you are saying and thanks for your help and response.

Comment: your answer helped me alot to find my problem actually i want to assign uid to screen name but it was creating issue. now i am trying to assign uid to userid by using portal-ext.properties but till now no success.

Comment: I am using oracle database with liferay .. is this can be the reason for late users import???

Comment: If you used the Control Panel GUI to do the mapping of the LDAP attributes, they are saved in the database. Once that happens, changes to the LDAP settings via portal-ext.properties will be ignored if they exist in the database. So if you used the GUI, continue using it for changing the mappings. Hope this helps

Comment: 10,000 approximately but for testing purpose there are 2000 something users which i am importing.

Comment: Do you need to do the bulk import of the users? What is your use case for all the users importing into the portal even if they never login? Is the directory or other uses? If not, I would suggest only doing import on login by just enabling the LDAP by unchecking import and import on startup. If you are only concerned about startup, you can try unchecking import on startup and increasing your import interval in the portal-ext.properties to 2-3 hours or more to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

OpenDJ has by default Access logs (logs/access) that will contain messages when connections are established, and some details of operations that happened on these connections.